# Como conectar usando el protocolo MQTT usando angular

Tags: angular, angular5

Tengo un problema, es sobre como conectarme usando al protocolo MQTT a un servidor broker, si alguien tiene algun conocimiento sobre eso me podria ayudar.
Tutorial,publicacion , cualquier cosa es bienvenido.
Soy nuevo en este tema.
Esto se hara con angular.

Comment: Pregunta del millón: ¿Has revisado la documentación? De ser afirmativa la respuesta, ¿qué has intentado?, de ser negativa la respuesta: ¿Cómo puedo ayudarte?

Comment: Soy nuevo en este protocolo mqtt y no tengo mucho conocimiento, me lo acaban de dejar y e estado buscando, soy sincero de la doc no entiendo mucho, me puedes ayudar

Comment: Comienza por entender que el frontend se comunica con el server, el server es el que se comunica con el protocolo mqtt, por lo tanto, vas a necesitar algún lenguaje de backend.

Comment: Ola en la documentacion existe un ejemplo hecho en nodejs, pero hay ciertos parametros que no me dicen de donde lo estan sacando :